# Select de tabelas SQL

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados

Bom dia pessoal!
Estou realizando o select abaixo:

```
select * from orcamento 
        where 
        status_orcamento = 'A' 
        and data_conclusao_orcamento > 2021-05-31
```

Minha dúvida é:
Deveria vir apenas informações acima do dia 31/05/2021 correto?

Comment: coloque a data entre aspas simples, vou fazer o cálculo de 2021 menos 5, menos 31

Comment: Esta conversão depende do banco utilizado e parâmetros internos , além do "type" da coluna (não sendo DATE terá comportamento).

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu certo.

Answer (score 2):

Não! O SQL está a reconhecer o seu "2021-05-31" como se fosse uma expressão matemática e não como uma data.
Experimente:

```
select * from orcamento 
        where 
        status_orcamento = 'A' 
        and data_conclusao_orcamento > Convert(datetime, '2021-05-31')
```

Ou então, uma forma não tão correta:

```
select * from orcamento 
        where 
        status_orcamento = 'A' 
        and data_conclusao_orcamento > '2021-05-31' ;
```

Diga se funcionou!

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu certo.

Comment: @DhionasRM pode só selecionar o "certo" para a resposta contar como correta? Obrigado!

Comment: Como posso fazer isso, sou novo no StackOverflow e não sei como se faz.

Comment: @DhionasRM Ao lado esquerdo da minha resposta deve estar um visto para confirmar que a pergunta foi bem respondida